# Sphinxbase-5prealpha Setup: Configure error: OpenAL not found on MacOS Mojave V 10.14.1

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

While setting up sphinxbase-5prealpha, I am getting

> Configure error: OpenAL not found

on MacOS Mojave V 10.14.1

My console looks like this:

```
$> cd sphinxbase-5prealpha
$> ./autogen.sh

configure: error: OpenAL not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Install and update xcode in mac.
Launch xcode to install additional components automatically by mac.
Run the command in terminal:
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: Answer received from https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569#issuecomment-94917337